# ionic platform add android error in windows 7

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following error and searched many answers from stack overflow and no luck! any one please guide me to right direction to fix this issue?

[image]

I have followed this tutorial http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/

Installed "android-19" target

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is to do with not having the SDK Platform at API level 19 installed. Your screen shot only shows the SDK Build Tool revisions installed. You need to check the SDK versions.

[image]

Comment: thank you dmc7337. now am in office..will check this in evening and let you know once checked SDK version.

Answer (score 1):

What you installed is build-tools 19. The error means you should install SDK platform 19.

[image]

Comment: thank you Jason. now am in office..will check this in evening and let you know once installed.